# Problem chaining Rails associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm somewhat of a Rails beginner, and can't shake the feeling that I'm overlooking something stupid, but here goes. I'm building a simple online game that allows one user to "challenge" another, and I have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_one :challenge
end

class Challenge < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :target, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

The database fields are what you'd expect: `Challenge` has a `user_id` and `target_id`, `User` has a `username` and some password-related fields.

From an empty database, I create two Users (which receive IDs 1 and 2) and a single `Challenge` with `user_id 1` and `target_id 2`. From the console, `Challenge.find(1).target` returns user 2, as expected. What's *not* expected is that `User.find(1).challenge.target` returns not user 2, but the `Challenge` itself!

Needless to say, I'm lost here. It seems like something this basic should Just Work(tm). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing things wrong here. User has one challenge should be like :

```
class User < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_one :challenge
end

class Challenge < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now, a challenge simply has a user_id and you can now use something like :

```
user.challenge
```

to get that challenge. Then, you just have a challenger_id for the person that makes the challenge.

If you want to get a challenge based on the challenger_id, you just create a finder or scope like :

```
Challenge.find_by_challenger_id(..)
```

EDIT - SOLUTION IN MY COMMENT BELOW :

> Hmm, i think that target is an
>   association method. Try changing to
>   something like challenger and i think
>   it will work.

Comment: Umm... I don't quite understand. It looks like all you're suggesting is to remove the "target" association (and switch the meaning/names of the Challenge fields? I'm not sure). The point of that association is so I don't have to do `User.find_by_id(some_challenge.target_id)` when I have `some_challenge` and want to know who it's targeting.

Comment: Hmm, ok then, you want to use 2 foreign keys. I think that it should be working as you have it now. Can you paste the exact output when you execute : User.find(1).challenge.target ? Is it just a challenge object ? What if you do User.find(1).challenge.target_id ?

Comment: The exact output of User.find(1).challenge.target is `#<Challenge id: 1, user_id: 1, target_id: 2, created_at: "2011-04-28 21:34:30", updated_at: "2011-05-07 02:14:46">`, and is completely identical to the output of User.find(1).challenge. Trying User.find(1).challenge.target_id returns 2 as expected.

Comment: Hmm, i think that target is an association method. Try changing to something like challenger and i think it will work.

Comment: Hey, that's it! I just changed the association name to "target_user" instead of "target" and suddenly everything works fine. You'd think Rails would complain about this conflict if you define an association named "target" though. The results are quite inscrutable!

Comment: It actually does not complain because association methods are the first ones to be inquired :) But yeah, a message would be helpful here.

Comment: Oh yeah, should I just accept this answer, or will you edit it or post a new answer? Not sure how this is supposed to go.

Comment: If this answer helped you get the solution(even in a comment), you can accept it :) I will also edit it for people to find the solution faster.